# How can I export a FULL war file from eclipse that bundles maven dependencies?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I have an eclipse WTP app using the M2 plugin.  I exported it and it runs fine on my machine, but I believe this is because it references my local maven repo.

How can I get it to bundle the jars from the maven repo into the war file ?

Is there a simple way to do this in eclipse with the M2 plugin >? Im afraid that if I muck with the pom.xml, which works so beautifully right now, that I will get sucked into a black hole of maven mysteries....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `pom.xml` should contain:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

This makes maven bundle all the dependencies* get bundled in `WEB-INF/lib` of the war.

Then you run `mvn:package` and the resultant war is placed in the `/target` folder of your project.

*some dependencies with scopes different from the default aren't included

Comment: How do you tell the POM file to automatically run the mvn:package command upon builds ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'build'. I run my build by calling mvn package.

Answer (score 0):

Check "Maven Dependencies" on "Order and Export" inside "Java Build Path" at the project properties.